# SharePoint - Dynamically Setting a property on a webpart. Possible with inline C# code block ? or Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint, dynamic, filter, properties, web-parts

I want to dynamically set the FilterValue1 property of a Content by Query to the querystring IDs value.

I tried to do it with an inline embed FilterValue1="<%= Reponse.Write .. but no luck

Without having to code my own webpart, any way to change the property value with a small C# code block on the aspx page?

How about with javascript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some code, but it is very simple and fast.

Please, take a look at great post from well-known SharePoint expert Andrew Connel:

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2008/02/18/Subclassing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-Adding-Dynamic-Filtering.aspx

As you see on last Andrew's screenshot, it is exactly what you need:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. However I think I'm going with a DataView solution.